# Which is the more HTML semantically correct way to code a hidden html field with a numeric value that the user is not expected to manipulate with

Tags: forms, html

In my examples the value will always be an integer. The user is not expected to change the value of the field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="14" name="user_id" readonly/>
<input type="number" value="14" name="user_id" class="hidden" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make a field hidden *in HTML* is to use `type="hidden"`. You may have been misled by the HTML5 feature `type="number"`. It’s not really comparable to typed variables in programming or types of fields in data formats. Instead, it is meant for creating a specialized user interface suitable for input of numeric data (such as a spinbox, possibly still allowing typing of numbers). This would be pointless, as you do not expect or even allow user input here.

Answer (score 2):

By the book, the correct answer is `<input type="hidden" etc... />` because the User Agent already have the rules on how to interact with such fields.

CSS or not, your field won't show up and it's better for accessibility etc. There's no way a user can interact with a hidden field (except javascript or editing the code locally). I would still validate the value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm genuinely of the opinion that it doesn't matter in the slightest since, with JavaScript, or CSS, they're both equally accessible to (relatively) knowledgeable users. However, and as a personal preference, I'd always use `type="hidden"`, since that seems to be what it was created for.

I would, though, recommend that you pick whichever you prefer and then use that approach consistently, but this is, really, a question of pure personal preference.